# How can i switch tabs when scrolling down in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-tablayout

I am working on a food delivery app where in a single store i have multiple categories. I have items in single recycler view.
So when i reach the header ( for example Breakfast then Breakfast tab should be active ) of each section how to change tab accordingly?[image: tab]

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: Any one have solution for this. how to do it?